# ListFragment with pagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-pageradapter

Please help a newbie out...
I am using this code as an example/learining exercise [LINK](http://androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

In tis example program there are three swipeable tabs using fragments.  I have created a new ListFragment that I would like to display in one of the tabs, but when Eclipse compiles, I get the following error in my PagerAdapter:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ContactListFragment to Fragment
```

Here is my code:

The PagerAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new ContactListFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}

}
```

Here is my ContactListFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ContactListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ContactAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ContactItem> contactItemList = new LinkedList<ContactItem>();

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public boolean taskRun = false;
    long currentID = 0;
    long currentContactID = 0;
    public ContactListFragment() {}
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        if(!taskRun){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ListContactTask task= new ListContactTask(getActivity(),ft);
            task.execute(); 
        }
        taskRun = true;
        mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, contactItemList);
        mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
        mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.lvmain);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter );
        ListView listView = getListView();
        getListView().invalidate();
    }

    public void setDataList( List<ContactItem> list) {  
        Activity act = getActivity();
        this.contactItemList = list;
        if(act != null) {
            mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(act, R.layout.lvmain,R.id.key, list);
            mAdapter .setInflater(mInflater);
            mAdapter.setLayout(R.layout.lvmain);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter );
            getListView().invalidate();
        }
    }
}
class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactItem> {

       private static String TAG = ContactAdapter.class.getName();
       private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
       List<ContactItem> pairList = null;
       private int layout;
       public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<ContactItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.pairList = objects;
        }

        public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater) {
            this.inflator = mInflater;
        }
        public void setLayout(int layout){
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         * 
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            try {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = this.inflator.inflate(
                            layout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.key = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.key);
                    holder.value = (TextView)     convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }else {
                     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                ContactItem pair = (ContactItem) getItem(position);
                String key = pair.mDisplayName;
                String value = pair.mPhone;

                holder.key.setText(key);
                holder.value.setText(value);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString(), e);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView key;
            TextView value;
        }

        public Filter getFilter() {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 1;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return pairList.size();
        }

        public ContactItem getItem(int position) {
            return (ContactItem) super.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return super.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return super.isEmpty();
        }
    }
```

My lvmain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just as an FYI, Everything compiles just fine before I try to add the ListFragment into the pager adapter.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ContactListFragment` class  `import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` it . 
I think it will work. 
Thank you

Comment: thank you. you need to accept it otherwise it will show as unanswered

Answer (score 1):

You imported `android.app.ListFragment` in the `ContactListFragment`. Try to import `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`. Also change `android.app.FragmentTransaction` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you.